# Deployment of a web application in AKS windows nodepool

Tags: azure-aks

I have deployed a owin hosted web applciation in AKS(windows nodepool). The container is in running state but  I am not able to hit the application. There might be runtime exceptions or errors but I am not able to figure out the path where I can see such errors in AKS Windows node.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

So, the ideal way here would be to use kubctl logs (which goes to Monitor, if you have that enabled). However, Windows containers don't pass on its logs to stdout by default. You have to use Log Monitor for that. Essentially, you have to enable Log Monitor on your container image to be able to get the logs out of the container just like you do with Linux containers. I blogged about it here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/troubleshooting-windows-containers-apps-on-azure-kubernetes/ba-p/3269767

The other thing you can try is to use kubectl exec to run a command inside the container and get its output.